# Jquery Load is Duplicating Behaviour in django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to populate a page using `jquery.load()` method. The loading is working fine but a form inside the newly loaded part is duplicating its behaviour on submit event.

**Relevant jquery part :**

```
$('#settings').on('click',function(event){
            var tax_submit_url = "{% url 'clinic_tax_submit' %}";
            $('.right_col:visible').load(tax_submit_url);
            return false;
      });
```

**HTML Part(inside dashboard.html)**

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
    <div class="menu_section">
    <ul class="nav side-menu">
        <li><a href="{% url 'clinic:clinic_dashboard' %}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home </a></li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Appointments <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
            <li id="doctors"><a>Doctors<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                {% for membership in memberships %}
                <li class="sub_menu membership_button" id="membership_{{membership.id}}" data="{% url 'clinic_doctor_scheduler' membership.doctor.slug %}"> 
                <a>
                <span><h6 style="margin:0">{{ membership.doctor }}</h6></span>
                <span style ="color:#1abb9c;"><small>{{ membership.doctor.doctorSpecial }}</small></span>
                </a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}  
            </ul>
            </li>  
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Billing & Invoicing <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
            <li id="invoicing_summary"><a> Invoicing Summary </a></li>
            <li id="settings"><a> Settings </a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /sidebar menu -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
</div>
```

**Form inside template**

```
<div class="col-xs-4" style="float:right;">
    <h3>Add Another Tax</h3>
    <br>
    <form class="taxes_form" method="POST" action="">
        {{ taxes_form.as_p }}   
        <button class="primaryAction btn-success" type="submit" style="width:100%;">Submit</button><br/>
    </form>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none !important;"> 
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> You have added a tax successfully!
    </div>
</div>
```

**View to render taxes.html which will be loaded in dashboard.html**

```
def clinic_tax_submit(request):
    print "inside clinic tax submit"
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        invoice_taxes = Invoice_taxes.objects.filter(clinic_id=request.user.clinic.id)
        context = {
            'invoice_taxes': invoice_taxes,
            'taxes_form': TaxesForm,
        }
        return render(request,'clinic/taxes.html',context)
    else:
        raise Http404()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is a hacky way to do things, if you don't find anything else, use event.stopImmediatePropagation() on the click event that is giving duplicate behaviour..!!